# What is a More Effective Title Seperator for SEO purposes? | or -

Tags: seo

What is the best separator for the title tag for SEO.

This

```
<title>This is a sample title - mysite.com</title>
```

or

```
<title>This is a sample title | mysite.com</title>
```

In Wordpress the SEO pack's default is |. What is the best separator as it relates to SEO? Why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a **programming-related** SEO question and may be better asked on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: More information on this from Matt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHSqLYUPq8w

Comment: The reason, I'd prefer a hyphen over pipe is the way things are read in a screen reader. VoiceOver will read a pipe character literally "vertical line", wheres a hyphen will be read as a longer pause.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Honestly these types of little things don't have much of a factor in SE algorithms.. the real factor in determining ranking is your content, make sure it's accessible and relevant to the user, make sure the crawlers can get to it.

Answer (score 5):

No real difference I think, beyond visual effect.

Makes a difference when saving the file (browser usually takes the title as file name) or dragging the URL to a folder (in Windows), as the pipe cannot be used in the file name (.html or .url) so have to be removed or replaced. Pipes are also annoying when I use Make Link Firefox extension with Wiki markup (as pipe is used as separator between link name and URL).
So pipe is slightly more annoying for these cases...

Answer (score 4):

Here is answer directly from a Google employee:

> Spaces, commas, pipes, dashes, ... All those things are good
>   separators. So in general I would say: Try to make a title that looks
>   pretty for users.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHSqLYUPq8w

Answer (score 3):

No one knows for sure, because the specifics of search rankings are secret.  However, I think it's reasonable to assume that they'd be both fairly equal in effect.

The more important thing is to put the page specific title first, then the site name, which you've done.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "page first, then site name"? Why do you say this? I currently have "domain | page name" across my site, you got me wondering if there's a reason I should change this?

Comment: @l008com Browser tabs truncate titles from the right. If you have several tabs from the same website, it doesn't help if they're all named "Stack Overflow - Wha..." That's just one reason. SEO is another. Both humans and search engines expect to see the important/specific part first. And whenever a title is truncated, it's the end that disappears first.

Comment: @Ariane I hear you, but it's it MORE likely that the average person is going to have multiple pages open from different websites, versus multiple pages from the same website? And in that more common situation, having the site name first will be more useful when viewing tabs or window titles etc.

Comment: But several pages from different sites being named the same is a relatively unlikely situation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally use the `|`, mainly because when you type `- mysite.com` it should be `-- mysite.com` (I cant type the correct dash here) as it's supposed to be an em dash, not a hyphen. But coding `&mdash` into a title may cause some issues.

Answer (score 1):

Note that many search engines use - as a negative operator in searches.  For example:  A search for shoes -brandname could actually end up filtering out the  search term if it's used in a copy & paste way.

So in my eyes, that makes the | operator gain a lot of traction.

Answer (score 0):

As former answers, it probably does not matter technically but you should consider maximizing the readability so users decide to click yours.
Especially for longer titles "-" is a better separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can test and see in Google Webmaster Tools which option gives you better CTR. Having high CTR is a good quality signal for search engines.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing a video at Google I/O channel, and "-" and "." was the best signs to use as a separator. Under score was interpreted as joining between words.

Answer (score 0):

I would tell pipe symbol (`|`) . Professional used one to separate the title tags. Infact SE doesn't consider much of these things.

Comment: Source? Why do you think pipe is better?

Answer (score 0):

| <- Pipeline always looked aesthetically pleasing to -. On most of our sites we use the pipeline, just looks a whole lot classier.

Answer (score -4):

I think that for humans and their subconscious a - sign is better because it connects
| divides
underscore in urls demands more effort because needs to press two keybord keys.

Comment: ...and the question isn't about humans, either.